# Warning: Return from incompatible pointer type

Tags: c

The code below is producing a compiler warning: return from incompatible pointer type. The type I'm returning seems to be the issue but I cant seem to fix this warning.

I have tried changing the type of hands to int *. Also have tried returning &hands.

```
int * dealDeck(int numPlayers, int numCards, int cardDeck[])
{
    static int hands[MAX_PLAYERS][MAX_CARDS]={0};

    int start = 0;
    int end = numCards;
    int player, hand, j;
    int card;

    for(player = 0; player < numPlayers; player++)
    {
        for(hand = start, j=0; hand < end; hand++,j++)
        {
            card =  cardDeck[hand];
            hands[player][j] = card;
        }
        start = end;
        end += numCards;
    }

    return hands;
}
```

This function should return a pointer to the array "hands". This array is then passed to another function which will print out its elements.

Comment: The 'handles' is 2 dimension array of integer, one per player. The 'dealDeck' indicate that it will return a single dimension array of integer. Either the return type need to be modified, or only of the arrays should be returned.

Comment: You might find it easier (and more conventional) to pass an array - which is defined where it is needed - to the function as an argument, instead of keeping it inaccessible.

Answer (score 1):

The `hands` variable is not an `int *` this is a `int **`
So you need to return a `int **`

This is a 2d array.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have declared return type of `int *`, which would mean, that you are trying to return an array, while you want to return a 2-dimensional array. The proper type for this would usually be `int **`, but that won't cut it here. You opted to go with static, fixed size array. That means, that you need to return pointer to some structures of size MAX_CARDS * sizeof(int) (and proper type, which is the real problem here). AFAIK, there is no way to specify that return type in C*.

There are many alternatives though. You could keep the static approach, if you specify only up to 1 size (`static int *hands[MAX_PLAYERS]` or `static int **hands`), but then you need to dynamically allocate the inner arrays.

The sane way to do it is usually "call by reference", where you define the array normally before calling the function and you pass it as a parameter to the function. The function then directly modifies the outside variables. While it will help massively, with the maintainability of your code, I was surprised to find out, that it doesn't get rid of the warning. That means, that the best solution is probably to dynamically allocate the array, before calling the function and then pass it as an argument to the function, so it can access it. This also solves the question of whether the array needs to be initialized, and whether `= {0}` is well readable way to do it (for multidimensional array) , since you'll have to initialize it "manually".

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define PLAYERS 10
#define DECKS   20

void foo(int **bar)
{
    bar[0][0] = 777;
    printf("%d", bar[0][0]);
    /*
     * no point in returning the array you were already given
     * but for the purposes of curiosity you could change the type from
     * void to int ** and "return bar;"
     */
}

int main()
{
    int **arr;

    arr = malloc(sizeof(int *) * PLAYERS);
    for (size_t d = 0; d < DECKS; d++) {
        /* calloc() here if you need the zero initialization */
        arr[d] = malloc(sizeof(int) * DECKS);
    }
    foo(arr);

    return 0;
}
```

---

*some compilers call such type like `int (*)[20]`, but that isn't valid C syntax